# Initializing LwIP causes RTOS to stop working

Tags: freertos, stm32f4, lwip

Good day

##### The goal:

I am trying to configure FreeRTOS and LwIP so that I can set up MQTT.

- I am using a STM32-NucleoF429ZI development board

##### What I have done:

1. I am using CubeMX to generate project files and I am using Visual Studio and VisualGDB for compiling and debugging.
2. I have set up FreeRTOS for the dev board using CMSIS_V2 and Heap_4.
3. I have set up LwIP with: `Static IP` and `MEM_SIZE of 1024*10`
4. I have kept all standard pinout (i.e. I have note cleared pinouts) of nucleo board
5. Ive set up an "Ethernet" thread and I am blinking and LED on the ethernet thread and the default thread.

Other than that no other setting has been changed. I did not set the MPU because as far as I can tell, this MCU does not have it.

##### The problem:

If I comment out the line `MX_LWIP_Init();`, (which cubeMX puts into the default thread), then the board runs fine and both LED's on both threads blink forever as far as I have tested. However, as soon as I leave `MX_LWIP_Init();`, FreeRTOS gets stuck as shown in the picture.

- This occurs anywhere from 30 seconds to many minutes after powering the board
- Please excuse the picture, but it shows where exactly the program is when I pause it. If I resume the debugger and pause it again, it always pauses in the same place.
- I have tried moving `MX_LWIP_Init();` into main.c with the other init functions and also into the ethernet thread where it should belong. All produce the same error at some point.
- I can ping the board once I add `MX_LWIP_Init();`

[image]

##### freertos.c

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * File Name          : freertos.c
  * Description        : Code for freertos applications
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2022 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "cmsis_os.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "config.h"

#include "EthernetLwIP_thread.h"

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Variables */

/* USER CODE END Variables */
/* Definitions for defaultTask */
osThreadId_t defaultTaskHandle;
const osThreadAttr_t defaultTask_attributes = {
  .name = "defaultTask",
  .stack_size = 128 * 4,
  .priority = (osPriority_t) osPriorityNormal,
};

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN FunctionPrototypes */

/* USER CODE END FunctionPrototypes */

void StartDefaultTask(void *argument);

extern void MX_LWIP_Init(void);
void MX_FREERTOS_Init(void); /* (MISRA C 2004 rule 8.1) */

/**
  * @brief  FreeRTOS initialization
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
void MX_FREERTOS_Init(void) {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_MUTEX */
    /* add mutexes, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_MUTEX */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_SEMAPHORES */
    /* add semaphores, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_SEMAPHORES */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_TIMERS */
    /* start timers, add new ones, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_TIMERS */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_QUEUES */
    /* add queues, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_QUEUES */

  /* Create the thread(s) */
  /* creation of defaultTask */
  defaultTaskHandle = osThreadNew(StartDefaultTask, NULL, &defaultTask_attributes);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_THREADS */
    if (EthernetModule_Init() == Result_Successful)
    {  
        logger("template module successfully initialized!!!");  
    }
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_THREADS */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_EVENTS */
    /* add events, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_EVENTS */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN Header_StartDefaultTask */
/**
  * @brief  Function implementing the defaultTask thread.
  * @param  argument: Not used
  * @retval None
  */
/* USER CODE END Header_StartDefaultTask */


void StartDefaultTask(void *argument)
{
  /* init code for LWIP */
  //MX_LWIP_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN StartDefaultTask */

    // Task timing
    TickType_t xLastWakeTime;
    xLastWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();
    const TickType_t xDelay_Ticks = 1000; // Current RTOS clock config has 1 tick equal 1ms. Thus 20 ticks sets a frequency of 50Hz

    /* Infinite loop */
    while (1)
    {
        vTaskDelayUntil(&xLastWakeTime, xDelay_Ticks); // waits until a certain number of ticks have passed before it starts this task again in a timely manner

        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_BLUE_PORT, LED_BLUE_PIN);
        //HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_RED_PORT, LED_RED_PIN);
        //HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_GREEN_PORT, LED_GREEN_PIN);
    }
  /* USER CODE END StartDefaultTask */
}

/* Private application code --------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Application */

/* USER CODE END Application */
```

##### Ethernet src file

```
/* Ethernet_thread.c */

// Includes: ----------------------------------------------------------
#include "EthernetLwIP_thread.h"
#include "config.h"


// Instantiations: ----------------------------------------------------

// Thread declaration: ------------------------------------------------
osThreadId_t EthernetModule_ThreadId;
const osThreadAttr_t EthernetModule_Attributes = {
    .name = "EthernetModule",
    .priority = (osPriority_t) osPriorityHigh,
    .stack_size = 1024 * 4                                                  // This needs to be optimized at a later stage
};
void EthernetModule_Thread(void *argument);

// Functions: --------------------------------------------------------

// Initializing functions: ---------------------------------------------------------------------
MResult EthernetModule_HardwareInit()
{
    return Result_Successful;
}

MResult EthernetModule_Init() {
    MX_LWIP_Init();

    if (EthernetModule_HardwareInit() == Result_Error)
        return Result_Error;

    EthernetModule_ThreadId = osThreadNew(EthernetModule_Thread, NULL, &EthernetModule_Attributes);
    if (EthernetModule_ThreadId == NULL)
        return Result_Error;
    
    return Result_Successful;
}

// Thread: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void EthernetModule_Thread(void *argument)
{
    // Task timing
    TickType_t xLastWakeTime;
    xLastWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();
    const TickType_t xDelay_Ticks = 500;

    while (1)
    {   
        vTaskDelayUntil(&xLastWakeTime, xDelay_Ticks);
        
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_GREEN_PORT, LED_GREEN_PIN);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the cause of this problem, but I have changed from FreeRTOS CMSIS_V2 to CMSIS_V1 and it resolved the issue. I dont know if there is a configuration in CMSIS_V2 that was wrong, or if there is an actual bug, but CMSIS_V1 and LwIP works great now.

Comment: does not work for me

Comment: Try rolling back CubeMx to V6.4.

Comment: I have used CubeIDE and the problem has been solved. It seems it was a memory problem.